# Calculate mean and standard deviation in a time-series

Tags: python, pandas, math, time-series, jupyter

I have the following dataframe:

```
    COD     ACT     DATE
0   5713    1.0     2020-07-16
1   5713    1.0     2020-08-11
2   5713    1.0     2020-06-20
3   5713    1.0     2020-06-19
4   5713    1.0     2020-06-01
5   23369   1.0     2020-07-17
6   23369   1.0     2020-08-07
7   23369   1.0     2020-09-02
8   23369   1.0     2020-11-22
9   32012   1.0     2020-06-02
10  32012   1.0     2020-07-26
```

I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation of each COD on the whole time series.
Previously I was calculating like this:

```
df['MEAN'] = df.groupby("COD")["ACT"].transform("mean")
df['STD'] = df.groupby("COD")["ACT"].transform("std")
```

But this calculated the mean for the time span of the initial timestamp for ACT and final timestamp for ACT (like 3 ACT within 5 months - not 8 months).
ACT is the timestamp for the activity, but the whole timeseries has 8 months. I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation for the whole 8 months. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is an apply function on the groupby. Make sure to convert the `DATE` column to a `datetime` object.

`df.groupby("COD").apply(lambda x: x["ACT"].mean())`

Here is a screenshot for more clarity. I also thought it might help to get a month wise sum and mean analysis for every `COD`.
[image]

Comment: I didn't understand one thing, for example the COD 5713 has 5 ACT's in diferent dates. Since the whole time series has 8 months the calculus shoudn't be 5/8=0.625 ACT/month? On the snapshot it says 1? Each COD should have a different mean since they have different ACT on the same time span.

Comment: On my previous implementation I got 1.0 for every COD as well. But it should be a different mean and std since their ACT is different.

Comment: But the data for 5713 spans only over 3 months. How did you get 8 months from this data?

Comment: Is spans over 8 months total but there isn't activity in every month. For example 5713 activity spans over 3 months only because it didin't have on the other months. But I would like the mean for all of the 8 months.

Comment: Then you can just take the 135th cell(the one with sum) and divide by 8 in the lambda function. That'll give you the mean over 8 months

Comment: How do I go about for the standard deviation though?

Comment: This should do `df.groupby("COD").apply(lambda x: (sum((x["ACT"] - x["ACT"].mean())**2)/8)**0.5 )`

Also just a [sugesstion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks!

Comment: That worked, thank you! I want to put these results (mean and standard deviation) in columns in front of the ortiginal data set. But when I assign them like this I get very different values:

df['Mean']=df.groupby("COD").apply(lambda x: x["ACT"].sum()/8)

df['Std']=df.groupby("COD").apply(lambda x: (sum((x["ACT"] - x["ACT"].mean())**2)/8)**0.5 )

I tried with round as well but values still appear very different then the single line results. How can I change that?

Comment: You can't add it as a column to the original dataframe. Look into https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html and see which function and attributes would work for your need. Consider the 2 dataframes-one is the original one and the other is the mean/standard deviation one.

Comment: Thank you very much! Great help!

Comment: Hi @Ananay , I wqs wondering if you could double check the formula for the std provided in the comment. The upper part uses the mean for the activity and the lower for the time (months). Just want to double check if it is correct? Shouldn't it be `df.groupby("COD").apply(lambda x: (sum((x["ACT"] - (x["ACT"].sum()/8))**2)/8)**0.5 )` ?

Comment: Yes this would be more accurate for how you described mean